# Asp:DropDownList is not working expect for internet explorer, issue ( browser compatibility)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

I have an old project (web application) which is around 3 years old. Now I am trying to make it browser compatible with new browsers. Dropdown list is doing fine with IE8 and firefox3.5. But not working with new Mozilla Firefox version 17 or chrome. When dropdown is clicked nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea about ??

Comment: Please include some code to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

set

AutoPostBack="True"..

this may help u

Comment: AutoPost is true and below is some part (required part) of the code as the entire file is too big.

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{bindDDLActions();}

public void bindDDLActions()
{
SqlParameter[] spar = new SqlParameter[0];
dt = objtcBLL.manageActions(spar, ref errMsg);
if (errMsg == string.Empty)
{
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
int count = dt.Rows.Count;
Int64 Tb002_Id = Convert.ToInt64(Session["ProjectID"]);
Int64 Tb005_Id = Convert.ToInt64(Session["TB005_Id"]);                   
ddlActionList1.DataSource = dt;
ddlActionList1.DataTextField = "Status";
ddlActionList1.DataValueField = "Tb011_Id";
ddlActionList1.DataBind();
ddlActionList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select ---", "0"));
}

Comment: this function enables the DropDownList

protected void btnDial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearFields();
        ddlActionList1.Enabled = true;
        btnDial.Enabled = false;
        btnRefresh.Enabled = false;
        hdIntime.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        BindAppAdditionalDetails();
        lblContactHead.Text = "Now Calling";
    }